# SSH Key not found logging into CentOS 5.5 from Windows (Cygwin)

Tags: centos, ssh, authentication, public-key

I am having difficulties logging in to a VPS running CentOS 5.5 using Public key authentication. I can log in to both a standard user account and the root account using password authentication. I am using Windows and Cygwin, all Cygwin and Windows stuff has been working completely fine for months; I am sure the issue is server side.

I have used ssh-keygen to create both an id_rsa private key and an id_rsa.pub public key. I have copied this into the user directory on the server and done `cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys`. My /home/myuser/.ssh directory is set to 700, the authorized_keys file is set to 600.

When logging in my system reports the following (-vvv):

```
Next authentication method: publickey
Offering RSA public key /.ssh/id_rsa
send_pubkey_test
we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

Then asks me for a password. From my server's /var/log/auth file I have the following related to the public key process

```
sshd[28249]: input_userauth_request: try method publickey
sshd[28249]: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
sshd[28249]: mm_key_allowed entering
sshd[28249]: mm_request_send entering: type 21
sshd[28249]: mm_key_allowed: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYALLOWED
sshd[28249]: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 22
sshd[28248]: monitor_read: checking request 21
sshd[28249]: mm_request_receive entering
sshd[28248]: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
sshd[28248]: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 0x2b6ea1049910
sshd[28248]: temporarily_use_uid: 10022/10022 (e=0/0)
sshd[28248]: trying public key file /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
sshd[28248]: secure_filename: checking '/home/myuser/.ssh'
sshd[28248]: secure_filename: checking '/home/myuser'
sshd[28248]: secure_filename: terminating check at '/home/myuser'
sshd[28248]: restore_uid: 0/0
sshd[28248]: key not found
sshd[28248]: temporarily_use_uid: 10022/10022 (e=0/0)
sshd[28248]: trying public key file /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
sshd[28248]: secure_filename: checking '/home/myuser/.ssh'
sshd[28248]: secure_filename: checking '/home/myuser'
sshd[28248]: secure_filename: terminating check at '/home/myuser '
sshd[28248]: restore_uid: 0/0
sshd[28248]: key not found
sshd[28248]: Normalising mapped IPv4 in IPv6 address
sshd[28248]: Failed publickey for myuser from 87.115.220.187 port 59636 ssh2
```

As if it can't find the authorized_keys file. However the command `nano /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` opens the file without issue.

From /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Some people have reported that line breaks in the authorized_keys file can cause issues so I've made sure there are none (only 1 key in it anyway). The file begins with `ssh-rsa` then has the long key and finally a space and `M1ke@M1ke-PC`.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Also the `myuser` directory is also set to `700`. Can't remember if I did that or it was already that way.

Comment: What about file ownerships? Does `myuser` own all the relevant dirs and files on the server side?

Comment: Can you append the following output to your question: `ls -ld /home/myuser/.ssh{,/authorized_keys}`. I suspect that perhaps the user doesn't own the directory and file?

Comment: Run sshd with debug, then it logs very clear info about permission issues via syslog.

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha In RHEL/CentOS this sort of information is logged to `/var/log/secure` without any modification to the configuration.

Comment: I posted the sshd debug log in the question. That output is with debug3 which I guess is the most verbose available, but if there's more let me know, as that info still doesn't explain everything.

Comment: To my knowledge the files and dirs are owned by my user, they appear this way in FileZilla if I browse to the dir. Will check in the morning with ls.

Comment: I can confirm that the /myuser & /myuser/.ssh directories are and the authorized_keys file is owned by myuser:myuser.

Comment: Please post `ssh -vvv mouser@SERVER` output from windows machine.

Comment: Edited it in, doesn't seem to add much but there we go.

Comment: Try running `col < authorized_keys >authorized_keys.bak` ;  `mv authorized_keys.bak authorized_keys` to fix line breaks.

Comment: No effect, the file is in the format `ssh-rsa *380 character string* M1ke@M1ke-PC` with no line breaks.

Comment: have you tried copying your private key to the server and login with it locally?

Comment: I'm unsure how to do that; are you meaning to SSH in to the server and then using that to SSH back into my client?

Answer (score 3):

If you really did do this `cat id_rsa.pub < authorized_keys` then your `authorized_keys` file won't then contain a public key to match the private key you are using so ssh falls back to password authentication. To fix the problem

```
cat id_rsa.pub >>authorized_keys
```

to add the new public key to your authorized_keys.

Comment: Um, no. `cat id_rsa.pub < authorized_keys` doesn't overwrite anything. But it definitely doesn't do anything useful, either. I suspect the question simply has a typo, replacing `<` for `>`.

Comment: You're right! but if the op did that then authorized_keys still won't have the correct public key and would be asked for the password.

Comment: True, but later in the question, OP mentions that he has inspected the `authorized_keys` file, and that it does contain (what he assumes to be) his public key.

Comment: ass u me - without any other evidence ...

Comment: Aha, now I believe I can agree with your answer. +1.

Comment: Steven is right, the file contains my public key (or at least, is identical to my public key) so I typo'd on that command in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is [SELinux](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) enabled ? 
If yes, the file requires context to be set.

Comment: a) How do I find out if it is enabled?
b) If so, how do I "set context"?

Comment: The link on the post has that information. Anyways, run "sestatus" as root to view the current selinux status. If it is enabled, you could disable selinux altogether as a temporary measure, until you completely read and understand on managing SELinux.

Comment: I looked up SELinux and ran "sestatus". It is set to "disabled".

Comment: What are the "PubkeyAuthentication" and "AuthorizedKeysFile" directives in /etc/ssh/sshd_config set to ?

Comment: Edited it into OP.

Comment: Finally, is there any "AllowUsers" directive in /etc/ssh/sshd_config ?

Comment: Searched for that and it is not present in the file.

Comment: Anything further on this?